# Behaviour of derivative in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider $f\in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose moreover $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Prove (or give a counterexample) that $f'\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

I bump into this question with a friend, and we have no idea if this is true or not. If we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of finite Lebesgue measure then it should be immediate, since then we can bound the integral with the $\infty$-norm of the derivative times the length of the interval, obtaining the thesis (I think).

But the case of the real line is still misterious: my gut feeling is this is true, because the hypothesis' are quite strong; I also thought that if $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ then the integral of the two tails of $f^p$  goes to $0$, so there exists a $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ compact in which $f^p$ has major impact in the integral; unfortunately I cannot say anything about the behaviour of the derivative, it may explode outside $K$.

I also think this is a pretty simple problem, but I'm missing the right way to see it. Any hint or answer would be much appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for sets of finite measure either. How do you know that $||f'||_\infty<\infty$???

Comment: Well, in the case of finite measure $(\mathcal{C}^1([a,b]),\left\lVert \cdot\right\rVert_{\mathcal{C}^1})$ you know $\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{\mathcal{C}^1}<\infty$... you're right, I should have add the norm, it was implicit in my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)} x
$$
with 
$$
f'(x) = 2 \cos(x^2) - \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}.
$$
This function is in $L^p(\mathbb R)$ for all $p>1$, and $f'$ is bounded but not in $L^q(\mathbb R)$ for all $q<\infty$.